# Location of cloud-init user-data.yml file

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-init

I want to bootstrap some raspi nodes with cloud-init. As of now I am testing this with a vagrantbox running ubuntu/jammy64.

My question now is: Where do I put my user-data.yml file so that cloud-init picks it up automatically omn the first startup? Or do I have to tell cloud-init where my user-data.yml is?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the [NoCloud Datasource](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources/nocloud.html?highlight=nocloud#nocloud), which uses a vfat or iso9660 filesystem for the cloud-config. Alternatively, if Vagrant allows passing command line arguments to the kernel (qemu does), that would work as well.

Comment: As far as I understand using NoCloud allows me to run cloud-init on a RasPi or in a Vagrantbox outside of any cloud ... I still have trouble getting started. Can't get my head around it. Is there some kind of tutorial?

Comment: Correct, you can run using NoCloud outside of a cloud. There is an example using qemu partway down the NoCloud docs (linked above). I would start there and then try adapting it to Vagrant. I think some tutorials might be out there for vagrant, but I can't attest to them. I plan on writing something up at some point but haven't gotten to it yet.